# What is the best approach to change a state when there are multiple view per state in a state machine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I have made a state machine in c# to change between views.

The problem began when I have divided my screen into multiple canvases.

For example, I have the outer menu, the inner screen, the hud.

Not in every state I want to see all of them.

For instance: 
The login screen only shows the login menu.

The market only shows the market menu and the outer menu (the outer menu is the logout button, the user details button).

The world map shows the world map screen, the outer menu and the hud.

**What I did:**

When changing state I just hide everything and show only the right ones, but it is not efficient.

**What I think I should do:**

Another approach I thought about is per state, per action only show and hide the relevant canvases for that specific change, however, it is overkill and requires tons of work, but kind of efficient.

**My question is:**

Is there any middle approach which is efficient and yet still easy to manage?

for the record here is the code I am using:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

        public LoginController loginController;
        public HudController hudController;
        public WorldMapController worldMapController;
        public MarketMenuController marketMenuController;

        public GameState currentState;
        public enum GameState
        {
            EntryMenu,
            WorldMap,
            MarketMenu,
        }

        protected Infrastructure.Base.Application.Application application;
        protected EventManager eventManager;

        void Start () 
        {
            ChangeState(GameState.EntryMenu);
            application = Infrastructure.Base.Application.Application.getInstance();
            eventManager = application.eventManager;
            application.eventManager.AddListener<LoginSuccessfulEvent>(this.OnLoginSuccessful);
            application.eventManager.AddListener<LogoutSuccessfulEvent>(this.OnLogoutSuccessful);
            application.eventManager.AddListener<PlayerOpenedMarketEvent>(this.OnPlayerOpenMarket);
            application.eventManager.AddListener<PlayerExitMarketEvent>(this.OnPlayerExitMarket);

        }

        void EntryMenuState()
        {
            loginController.Show();
        }

        void WorldMapState()
        {
            hudController.Show();
            worldMapController.Show();
        }

        void StarOrbitState()
        {
            hudController.Show();
            starScreenController.Show();
        }

        void StarMenuState()
        {
            hudController.Show();
            starMenuController.Show();
        }

        void MarketMenuState()
        {
            hudController.Show();
            marketMenuController.Show();
        }

        public void ChangeState(GameState newState)
        {
            HideAll();
            currentState = newState;
            StartCoroutine(newState.ToString() + "State", currentState);
        }

        void OnLoginSuccessful(LoginSuccessfulEvent e)
        {
            ChangeState(GameState.MarketMenu);
        }

        void OnLogoutSuccessful(LogoutSuccessfulEvent e)
        {
            ChangeState(GameState.EntryMenu);
        }

        void OnPlayerExitStarMenu(PlayerDepartFromStarEvent e)
        {
            ChangeState(GameState.StarOrbit);
        }

        void OnPlayerOpenMarket(PlayerOpenedMarketEvent e)
        {
            ChangeState(GameState.MarketMenu);
        }

        void OnPlayerExitMarket(PlayerExitMarketEvent e)
        {
            ChangeState(GameState.StarMenu);
        }

        void HideAll()
        {
            loginController.Hide();
            worldMapController.Hide();
            hudController.Hide();
            marketMenuController.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too broad and _"best"_ is subject to opinion. [ask]

Comment: don't overthink it. it sounds like you're in a game loop? define a flag set and constants with the combinations of flags you're going to use, then switch those on context transition. renderer can then `HasFlag`-query individual items to display.

Comment: @dlatikay are you saying use something like MENU1 | MENU2 etc? Are how are you going to hide the already shown screens?